# How does NonlinearModelFit work?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, nonlinear

Suppose I have a model $ f (x) $ with some free parameters $ a, b $ and I want to fit my model to a data set called Dx.

How does `NonlinearModelFit` find the value of the parameters $a$ and $b$? Is it minimizing the $\chi^{2}$ statistics?

Comment: Not sure, but in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html): _Possible settings for Method include "ConjugateGradient", "Gradient", "LevenbergMarquardt", "Newton", "NMinimize", and "QuasiNewton", with the default being Automatic._

Comment: Those are methods to find the minimum of some quantity, what quantity are minimizing? Is the $\chi^{2}$?

Comment: I imagine it's minimizing the residuals  - the (square?) error between the data and the model predictions, possibly regularized too.

Comment: @flinty is correct.  It minimizes the sum of squares of the residuals.  If one can assume that the errors have a normal distribution, then this is equivalent to maximizing the likelihood (or equivalently maximizing the log of the likelihood in practice).  The residual error variance estimate is not, however, the maximum likelihood estimate of the variance as `NonlinearModelFit` divides the sum of the squares of the residuals by the sample size minus the number of parameters.  (And it must be a thing taught in physics classes to use the term "minimizing the $\chi^2$ statistics".)